# zii.widgets.CListView with CStarRating doesn't reload stars jquery on pagination

Tags: php, jquery, yii

Houdi !

I have an Yii webpage that I'm listing a bunch of products that I load like so :

```
 $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
'itemView'=>'_listareProduse',  ));
```

and in the _listare produse I'm loading the star rating widget like so :

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
                $criteria->condition = "product_id='".$data->product_id."'";
                $rating = Rating::model()->findAll($criteria);

        echo CHtml::beginForm();
        $this->widget('CStarRating',array(
                'name'=>'rating',
                'value'=> $rating[0]->rating,
                'readOnly'=>true,
                ));
        echo CHtml::endForm();
```

When I load the page all loads good, after I hit a number or next /prev from pagination it does the pagination but the CStarRating fails to load

Any idea why? Tried to put 'id' => '#qwerty' in the ClistView but it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are loading the pages by ajax, you loaded the js for rating at page load ( via the widget call) this piece of js does not know that the DOM has changed, so you will have to reinitialize the `CStarRating` widget you can add this to your `ListView`

```
 $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_listareProduse',  
    'afterAjaxUpdate'=>'js:function(){
            $("[id^=rating] > input").rating({"readOnly":true}); 
     }',
 ));
```

Also you need to change the `itemView`, as you are using the same id "rating" for all ratings, id should be unique in HTML as you know. I have added the id of the row along with rating , so will you rating1 rating2 etc , if you wish to some other key, remember to adjust the `afterAjaxUpdate` call accordingly

```
$this->widget('CStarRating',array(
                'name'=>'rating'.$data->id,
                'value'=> $rating[0]->rating,
                'readOnly'=>true,
                ));
```

Comment: I modified the code as you posted but still no result :

so : added in the Star rating widget :  'name'=>'rating'.$data->product_id,

and the Ajax part exactly as you posted ( copy pasted ) dunno if i should modifie something in it

Comment: oke i got it : i had to modifi and add at afterAjaxUpdate id^=rating'.$data->product_id.'... 

Thanku Sir ! you are my hero for today ! dident find this piece of advice anywhere on the net. couldent do it alone ;)

Comment: as long as it solves the problem :), i had similar problem sometime back